# SVN : Add colors on command-line svn with awk (in bash)

Tags: svn, bash, awk

**EDIT:** Here is the [GitHub updated version](https://github.com/4wk-/beautifulSVN) of this snippet, stable.

---

Here is a part of Bash code (I put it in *.bashrc* file) which **works**:

```
function svn {
  command svn "$@" | awk '
  BEGIN {
    cpt_c=0;
  }
  {
    if        ($1=="C") {
      cpt_c=cpt_c+1;
      print "\033[31m" $0 "\033[00m";  # Conflicts are displayed in red
    }
    else if   ($1=="A") {
      print "\033[32m" $0 "\033[00m";  # Add in green
    }
    else if   ($1=="?") {
      print "\033[36m" $0 "\033[00m";  # New in cyan
    }
    else if   ($1=="D") {
      print "\033[35m" $0 "\033[00m";  # Delete in magenta
    }
    else                {
      print $0;                        # No color, just print the line
    }
  }
  END {
    print cpt_c, " conflicts are found.";
  }';
}
```

This part of code do exactly what I want. svn functions (status, update, etc.) are printed with colors. For internally needs, I don't want to install such things as [colorsvn](http://colorsvn.tigris.org/) or [svn-color](https://github.com/jmlacroix/svn-color/blob/master/svn-color.sh).

Here is an example of the code above:
[image: svn command displayed in colors]

And again, **that is perfectly what I want**. The problem happens when a conflict is found (for instance when I do an update): indeed, when a file is conflicted, svn is handed over to the user, to let him type a few letters (see below)

```
# svn update
Conflict discovered in 'test.txt'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
        (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
        (s) show all options:
```

Is there a way to awk to let the user type something (*for instance e, which open in VIm the conflicted file*), do something (*for instance delete some lines after type e, then save&quit*), and type another letter to confirm solving conflict, then finally display the next step of svn update (others files, etc)?

In other words, I want to "pause" the script which display colors to let user interact with svn, then svn update go on. I think it 'll be very useful for future to know how can let awk pause the caller script, then resume!

Comment: Your `command svn` still gets your input. There are tools like `expect` to switch between autonomous and interactive execution, but it might be somewhat beside the point here. The correct solution is a lower-level wrapper, I guess like the ones you said you don't want to use. Your awk script receives its input frim a pipe but you could perhaps hack something in to add a mode where it reads additional input from `/dev/tty` or some such.

Comment: Do you want to extend your bash function `svn` to handle all of this, or do you envision that the required 'pausing' as seperate code after the `svn` function has run? Incidentally your english is fine! Good luck.

Comment: @shellter : Well, I would like to extend my bash function, it 'll be the best. But I'm open about all possible solutions ;)
Ty for my english !

Comment: @Ash_ There are two things I noticed while testing your script. First, there are some options missing: X and U. Second, when I run `svn commit` the editor (vim in my case) opens - though, I cannot edit the commit in any way. The keyboard input ends up somewhere else.

Comment: @JJD Indeed, I don't add X and U options, cause I don't need it colorized. However, why `svn commit` open VIm (it's my editor too) ? In my case, `svn` ask the user to write something exclusivly when I do an update which create a conflict.

Comment: @Ash_ I am not sure if understand each other. I need to run `svn ci` to commit my changes into the repository. That means I also need to add a commit message with it. Since I cannot physically enter any character into `vi` when your script is active I cannot write my commit message or even exit `vi`.

Comment: Here is the exact error message that appears when I run `svn ci`: `Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal`

Comment: It seems I cannot understand you :/ In my case, I only have conflicts when I do a `svn update` not a `svn ci` like you. When I do a commit, yes I run `svn ci -m "MyMessage"` but I don't have any problem with my script when using `svn commit` command.

Comment: Try to run `svn ci` only which should open `vi` (if no other editor is configured). The short message `svn ci -m` is not always applicable, e.g. in case I need to enter more then a one-line commit message.

Comment: Here is a post witch explain step by step my problem http://www.logicaltrinkets.com/wordpress/?p=178 . But I just discovered one thing : on another server, a svn conflict is not displayed like mine, it just wirte a "C", and not offer me the position to edit "in live" my file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to run `svn update --accept postpone` so that `svn` doesn't prompt for conflicts?

Comment: Man, this is PERFECT. No more prompt for conflict ... So I can keep my entire script ! Thanks a lot, that was obvious but I didn't find out !

Comment: NOTE : in order to avoid **ALL SVN prompts**, it is better to use the `--non-interactive` option (for any SVN subcommand).

Answer (score 2):

Although not particularly answering your question - I created a slightly modified and version of your script in which I bypass `awk` when running `svn commit`. Further, I added more colors to certain types of output. The script is available online - please feel free to commit your changes.

- https://gist.github.com/1790203

Comment: Wow, I feel a bit flattering ! That's fine you add some color. But as I told it, in case of file are conflicting during a svn update, I think you will have the same problem I have : `Conflict discovered in 'offres.php'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
        (h) help for more options: `

Comment: My setup is different. I am using an `svn` repository and a `git` repository in parallel. Conflicts are resolved via `git` only. Each time I commit into `svn` I will not have any conflicts. - I would need to setup some test project to reproduce your conflict. No offence! I use your script out of selfish "color" reasons. However, I can look at your problem in March the earliest since I will be on vacation in the meantime.

Comment: At last, 4+ years later, I've decided to share my version of this snippet through GitHub, just like you did in the past ;) I've made many improvement, so if anyone is interested in, please look at [this up-to-date version of beautifulSVN](https://github.com/4wk-/beautifulSVN)

Comment: Nice! Thanks for sharing. - Although, I must admit I am using Git nowadays and I will resist as hard as I can to work with SVN ever again. No offense please.

Comment: Don't worry, only our oldest project are still managed through `svn` ;) we use `git`a lot more!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple and safe workaround (tested with your script). Because svn simply calls

```
system(getenv("SVN_EDITOR")) // or something similar
```

you simply can do the following (in bash, adjust for other shells):

```
export SVN_EDITOR="</dev/tty >&/dev/tty vi"
```

You will then be able to do your edits, and keep your coloring scheme from awk.

I don't know whether it works with other editors, but I hope it does. It should given these are standard redirects.

Comment: I 'll do some test this weekend, and tell you what is going on, thanks!